# What is _id field in array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema like:

```
matrix: [ {
  name: {type: String},
  inflow: {type: Boolean},
  activities: {type: Number, default: 0}
}]
```

But after save document I have got:

```
"matrix" : [ {
  "name" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "inflow" : false,
  "_id" : ObjectId("sdada342342342ds343"),
  "activities" : 0 },
  ...
]
```

Why does mongoose add "_id" field to matrix object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo DB automatically adds an ID if none given.
It's like a primary key in SQL. It makes your db able to deals with unicity : each line has a unique ID.

Imagine two rows with the same data in them : how to differenciate them ? You can only do this with a unique key, which is _id.

Comment: The question is about the `_id` attribute in *sub*-documents. MongoDB does not add these but Mongoose.

Comment: @str I see... Didn't understood this way. Thanks for precising !